# how to run composer require phpunit/phpunit

Tags: phpunit

I run this code for phpunit

```
composer require phpunit/phpunit
```

but error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LASIU.png)

thanks

Comment: due to some of your dependencies mismatch, this could not be done. please check your php version

Comment: i run --> php -v is 7.2.5

Comment: phpunit -version is 3.7.21

Comment: but i run ---> composer require phpunit/phpunit same previous error... i have a question---> it need run composer require phpunit/phpunit ?

Comment: https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-7.html

Comment: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/installation.html

Comment: those link may help you. I'm not getting clear about your problems

Comment: thanks, i saw your link. and i clear all project and the first one run --> composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^7     and i think must to do  configureation

Comment: i want to show you image.. how? because i write code but undefine libaray...... this libaray \PHPUnit_Framwork_TestCase

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=Untitled.png

Comment: you can see my image in this link